# Concerning Categories and Multisets

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm doing a question in Algebra Chapter 0, and in it, it asking me to define a category that "mimics" multi sets with appropriate morphisms.
I was wondering if my approach is correct.

Let, $\mathbf{Mset}$ be a category.

$Obj(\mathbf{Mset}) :=$ Sets endowed with an equivalence relation such that two elements are equivalent if they are of the "same kind".

Let $A,B \in Obj(\mathbf{Mset})$.

$Hom(A,B) :=  \begin{cases} 
      \{f|  f:A \rightarrow B \} & A \simeq \mathcal{P}(A) \wedge B \simeq \mathcal{P}(B) \\
       \{f| f:\mathcal{P}(A) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}(B) \} & (else) 
   \end{cases}
$

Would this be a possible interperation of $\mathbf{Mset}$, and will this interperation allow the category $\mathbf{set}$ to be contained within $\mathbf{Mset}$?

The powerset  is with respect to the equivalence relation that the sets are endowed with.

Comment: You need to be a _lot_ more precise about what your morphisms are, and also explain what you want composition to be.

Comment: I guess what I wanted to say was that the morph isms would be a set of functions that go from A to B if there exists an isomorphism from A to the power set of A and from B to the power set of B. Else, I would want  a set of functions from the power set of A to the power set of B.

Comment: In particular, it is not at all clear what you mean by $A\simeq\mathcal{P}(A)$, or what it means to take a powerset "with respect to the equivalence relation", or what any of this would have to do with multisets.